# Spring Data JPA + EclipseLink in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, eclipselink

I have this repository:

```
@Repository
public interface EnvaRepository extends JpaRepository<Enva, Long> {
}
```

and this query:

```
 envaRepository.findAllById(lopn.getEnvans());
```

but on console I have this error:

```
SELECT t0.PERSONNE_ID, t0.DT_NAISSANCE, t1.PERSONNE_ID FROM PERSONNE t0, ENVA t1
WHERE ((t0.PERSONNE_ID IN ((777,777))) AND (t1.PERSONNE_ID = t0.PERSONNE_ID));

[42000][907] ORA-00907: parenthèse de droite absente
```

My config class:

```
@Configuration
public class JpaConfiguration extends JpaBaseConfiguration {

    protected JpaConfiguration(DataSource dataSource, JpaProperties properties, ObjectProvider<JtaTransactionManager> jtaTransactionManager, ObjectProvider<TransactionManagerCustomizers> transactionManagerCustomizers) {
        super(dataSource, properties, jtaTransactionManager, transactionManagerCustomizers);
    }

    @Override
    protected AbstractJpaVendorAdapter createJpaVendorAdapter() {
        log.debug("Using EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter");
        return new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public static JpaProperties properties() {
        final JpaProperties jpaProperties = new JpaProperties();
        jpaProperties.setShowSql(true);
        jpaProperties.setDatabasePlatform("org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.OraclePlatform");
        return jpaProperties;
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, Object> getVendorProperties() {
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.WEAVING, detectWeavingMode());
        return map;
    }

    private String detectWeavingMode() {
        return InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver.isInstrumentationAvailable() ? "true" : "static";
    }
}
```

Comment: How is spring building the JPQL query? It needs to be using " .. in :variable " and not wrap the collection variable in brackets to work.

Comment: Can you share your Enva entity ? Are you calling any other query other than this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM Enva e where e.personneId IN :envantIds")
    List<Enva> findAllById(Iterable<Long> envantIds);
```

Answer (score 0):

get rid of extra parenthesis in your IN statement like so:

```
SELECT t0.PERSONNE_ID, t0.DT_NAISSANCE, t1.PERSONNE_ID 
FROM PERSONNE t0, ENVA t1
WHERE ((t0.PERSONNE_ID IN (777,777)) 
AND (t1.PERSONNE_ID = t0.PERSONNE_ID));
```

Comment: The query is automatically build for EclipseLink

Comment: I'm not familiar with EclispeLink but maybe there is configuration somewhere or it can be a real bug !